# What technology can help me search, filter and group across any columns in a wide dataset quickly?

Tags: database, analytics, data-warehouse

We have certain datasets which may span 80 to 300 fields, across 300,000 to 35 million rows.

For each dataset, we want to produce an analysis tool which would allow our users to pick the fields they want, and perform filtering on any of these fields.  In addition, they should also be able to group by any number of these fields, and sort by any of these fields.

Our source data is spread across several tables in SQL Server and while the above is possible via dynamic SQL, it is slow.  Even if we generate a precomputed table with all of the columns in it, performing analysis on this is slow;  adding another column to group by can add a few seconds to the query time.

Since we do not know ahead of time which fields would be queried on the most, we cannot put indexes on specific columns.  On the other hand, (correct me) I don't believe it's best to place 80 indexes on a table.

Which technologies are better suited for this kind of a task with better response times?  And what kind of response times should I be expecting?  Is this a job for a data warehouse tool?  Which one would you recommend for this?

To be specific, we will be building an interactive grid in AngularJS which calls out to an API with the fields the user wants to query, group, filter, sort on.  The API is in C# and its current backend is SQL Server, but we can look at something else if needed. It would be nice to have the query results return in a few seconds

Answer (score 0):

Do you know about [MapReduce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MapReduce)? This is how Google handles their large Datasets.

Comment: I hadn't considered it, I thought I'd be picking between SSAS or some alternative.  Would this be suitable as a website backend? (Can it return results within a few seconds).

Comment: I am not an expert in MapReduce. As far as I know, MapReduce is about running the query parallel. I don't know about your about your Architecture. If running the query in parallel is an option for you. You should consider MapReduce IMHO. There can be a lot of reasons why queries run slow. Sometimes rebuilding the queries in a different way can increase the speed of the query as the DB translates the query in a different way.